# Ruby on Rails Guides | partial variable - cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am following Ruby on Rails Guides and I have an error in rendering partial when I want to create a new article:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Marked error is from partial _form.html.erb located in the same place as index:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

index.html.erb has link:

```
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>
```

controller:

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end
```

form partial:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %><br>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb which renders partial:

```
<h1>New article</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller needs a `new` method

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

that way there's an @article object that the form_for can reference.

When you follow a `new` link, the `new` action is executed and the form is displayed. It's only when the form is submitted that the `create` action is executed.